# Setting Postman env variable based on the repsonse where certain criteria is met

Tags: arrays, if-statement, postman

When I get a response in Postman, I want to be able to set an environment variable (using

```
pm.environment.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

when a condition is met from the response array.

So the requirements:

- set an environment variable named `idForAbc` to the value of `someArray.id` where `someArray.criteria = "ABC"` (so `idForAbc = 1`)
- set an environment variable named `idForXyz` to the value of `someArray.id` where `someArray.criteria = "XYZ"` (so `idForXyz = 2`)

Here is my sample response:

[image: Example Response]

Comment: It's better if you put sample response in text format, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose one of 2 ways:

```
const res = pm.response.json();

const abc = res.someArray.find(e => e.criteria === "ABC");
if(abc){
    pm.environment.set(`idFor${abc.criteria}`,abc.id)
}

const xyz = res.someArray.find(e => e.criteria === "XYZ");
if(xyz){
    pm.environment.set(`idFor${xyz.criteria}`,xyz.id)
}
```

or

```
const res = pm.response.json();

function saveVarByCriteria(arr, value){
    const obj = arr.find(e => e.criteria === value);
    if(obj){
        pm.environment.set(`idFor${obj.criteria}`, obj.id)
    }
}

saveVarByCriteria(res.someArray, "ABC");
saveVarByCriteria(res.someArray, "XYZ");
```

Comment: Excellent thanks fo much. I used the first example you provided and worked great.